# Moon's and nodes' inclination to the Invariable plane

Tags: orbit, the-moon, orbital-mechanics

Moon is inclined to the ecliptic 5.14 degrees. Earth's inclination to the invariable plane is 1.57869 degrees.

What is the Moon's, and node's inclination to the invariable plane?

Since the Moon has an inclination to the invariable plane, that means at any point in time the degree of inclination is different depending on the Earth's position. where can I get this information of planets' inclination degree at any date? Calculated by NASA JPL Horizon?

Comment: Please fix your earlier question on this topic: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41190/16685

Comment: I will be deleing that question after I post all those questions in little parts as separate questions.